# Why must all natural processes be irreversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, dissipation

My thermodynamics lecturer was talking about reversibility and the idea of spontaneous change and he mentioned that all natural processes are irreversible.

Can someone offer some sort of proof or reasoning as to why nature can not produce any reversible change on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "all natural processes are irreversible."

Yes, but no.

Most physical process are reversible when you describe them at the atomic scale. The problem is, any macroscopic system has so many atoms that the number of possible states they all could be in is inconceivably huge. Furthermore, the number of states that are uninteresting (a.k.a., "disordered") is inconceivably huger than the number of interesting (a.k.a., "ordered") states.

When you have a bunch of atoms all jiggling around and bumping into each other (e.g., gas molecules in a box), You will never, ever, ever see the system *spontaneously* move from a "disordered" state (e.g., same temperature everywhere in the box) to an "ordered" state (e.g., hot on one side, and cold on the other). That's not because it's impossible, but merely because the probability of it happening is so inconceivably small.

To learn more, read about *[entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)*.

Comment: So you are saying that the individual motion of each particle is reversible, but as the number of disordered systems are several orders of magnitude more than the number of ordered systems, the chance a disordered system reversibly evolving into ordered system is negligible.
Something still feels a bit intuitive here. 
If the motion of each atom is reversible, when the system makes a spontaneous change , why is the overall motion considered irreversible when the movement of each atom was reversible.

Comment: microscopically vs macroscopically irreversible are two different things

Comment: Could you expand on the difference?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a thermodynamic process to be reversible in nature it must be done in infinitesimally small steps such that at each stage, thermodynamic equilibrium is maintained. This would take infinite time to complete and is hence impossible in nature. You will also have energy leaking out due to various other factors such as friction, collision etc.